# Visual Studio 2013 wrong intellisense suggestions for javascript

Tags: javascript, visual-studio, intellisense

This is bugging me for a while everytime I write code in javascript.
Intellisense always suggests wrong tips like: Document instead of document,
Console.Log, instead of console.log:

[image]

I'm not sure what lib.d.ts is. But this so annoying. Thank you so much.

Comment: What if you try to find `lib.d.ts` on your computer? Maybe it's in some editable format like plaintext or zip archive (7z will detect most kinds of archives and open them). In that case, you'd be probably able to delete unwanted expressions. And maybe add your own while you're at it :)